# Magento - Multiple Stores, get the store the product was added to the cart from

Tags: magento, customization, shopping-cart

I have a multisite Magento install with one website and four stores, and would like to display the store the product was added into the cart from in the cart next to each product (similar to how Gap.com does it). So customers know what store each item came from.

Any ideas how I would go about doing this?

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Sounds like you would like all of the items grouped by store as well, not just a rendered output per store. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way would be, to use `$_item->getStoreId()` to differ the stores of each item within your template at `template/checkout/cart/render/default.phtml`.

In the standard Magento `default.phtml` template, `$_item` gets assigned the current item to be rendered (at the very top of the template code).

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
```

Thereafter you can easily assign the items proper store name to a variable, like this:

```
<?php
$aStore = array(
    '1' => 'Red Store',
    '2' => 'Green Store',
    '3' => 'Blue Store',
    '4' => 'Yummy Store'
);
$sStore = $aStore[$_item->getStoreId()];
?>
```

This allows you to output the name wherever you want, using `<?php echo $sStore; ?>`.

Another possibility would be to override `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` and create a public getter method, returning the store name of the given item.

But that's another story and maybe like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut^^

Comment: An array literal is too inflexible, instead use `Mage::app()->getStore($_item->getStoreId())->getName()`

Comment: I used the array by intention, because we don't know, what exactly the OP wants to display next to the product (maybe logos or whatever). I'd agree though, if he just wants to show the same store names as defined in the backend, so +1.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I'll try the code out shortly and let you know how it goes! :-)

Comment: Works spot on! Thanks @Jürgen Thelen